# Group List view in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have a list of countries and I want to display them grouping by continents. 
My models.py looks like this

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And, my views.py looks like this:

```
class ListCountriesView(ListView):
    model = Countries
    template_name = 'country_list.html'
```

My html displays the folowing list

```
 Asia
 Japan
 Asia
 S.Korean
 Asia
 China
 Asia
 India
 Europe
 Germany
 Europe
 France
 Europe
 Belgium
 Africa
 Ghana
```

My country_list.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><th>Country</th></tr>
{% for country in object_list%}
     <td>kpi.continent</td>
     <tr><td>country.name</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

I want to display the continent's name once and followed by the respective cooutries. I cannot figure out how to group the list by continent.Is there any fllter function that I can use in django template ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. There certainly is:

```
{% regroup object_list by continent as continents_list %}

<ul>
{% for continent in continents_list %}
    <li>{{ continent.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in continent.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[More in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: Wow, pretty much the exact same example in the Django Docs!

Comment: yep. django docs are pretty awesome. if this answers your question, do you mind marking answer as accepted? thanks

Comment: @miki725 yes, that certainly solved my problem for now. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

it helped solve my problem as a Django newbie.  As an aside I was using a Django standard List View to display event winners by event.  The regroup helped me to group by events as above, but my order for the podium finishers was being displayed randomly.  This was solved by ordering the List View as per the code snippet.

```
class WinnerListView(ListView):
    model = Winner
    template_name = "scores/winners.html"
    context_object_name = "winners"
    ordering = ["score_id__sevent", "-prize"]
    paginate_by = 16
```